# Kendo UI Scheduler Event Count Summary Row

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm having an issue with the Kendo UI Scheduler. I've been asked to add a row per user which will display a count of the number of tasks scheduled for each week, and I can't find any officially documented way to do that.

I have a layout which is slightly different to the normal, as can be seen in the image below. I have my scheduled tasks grouped by user, client and task type, then displayed per week (it is the week number in the column headers).

[image: An example layout of my scheduler]

What I would require is for an additional row grouped under each user which rather than having a Kendo task in the column would display a number, e.g. 0 for week 43 and 3 for week 45 in the image above.

I am aware that I can do this by hijacking the table building process to add the row in manually, but before I do that I was wondering if anybody on here had ever had a similar requirement and had found a more elegant solution?

Thank you.